# Mongodb: Not able to run mongo log files with edda

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to open my mongod.log file with [edda](https://github.com/10gen-labs/edda) but not able to open it. I have tried with this command >root@shalu-desktop:~# python edda/run_edda.py /home/Desktop/mongod.log

But getting error: >python: can't open file 'edda/run_edda.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Doesn't appear to be installed or is not installed where you are trying to run from. How did you install?

Comment: I have installed it with pip:  pip install edda and edda version is > root@shalu-desktop:~# edda --version
Running edda version 0.7.0

Comment: Sounds like you are taking the manual page too literally. You installed to somewhere in your path, probably `/usr/local/bin` just run `edda <logfilename>` straight from the command line.

Comment: First i have tried running like this only < root@shalu-desktop:~# edda /home/shalu/Desktop/mongod.log 

Currently parsing log-file: /home/shalu/Desktop/mongod.log
[===================================================================================================]100%CRITICAL:edda.run_edda:No servers were found, exiting.
but got this error

Answer (score 0):

At this time, the current version of edda on pip doesn't support current versions of mongodb, which is most likely why you got a critical error when you tried to run with `edda <logfile>`.  The [master branch on github](https://github.com/10gen-labs/edda) does support current versions, however, so you should be able to clone into edda and run it from there.

If you're running from the repository, make sure that you are in the proper directory where the run_edda.py script is when you try to run it. The script is actually two levels deep (edda/edda/run_edda.py) so navigate into the directory before you try `python edda/run_edda.py <logfiles>`.

I believe [this discussion on the repository](https://github.com/10gen-labs/edda/issues/124) is covering the same question that you've posted here.